# Is it possible to enable ServiceStack auth across a webfarm without a shared session state storage?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, servicestack, session-state, servicestack-auth

With ASP.NET Forms Authentication, its possible to setup all the servers in a webfarm to share the same machine key for encryption of authentication tickets, meaning if you can get by without requiring session state in your application scale out to a web farm is easy.

i.e., http://www.iambacon.co.uk/blog/getting-asp-net-authentication-to-work-on-a-web-farm

Is there a method to do accomplish this disconnected setup using ServiceStack Authentication, or does implementation require a shared session state to be persisted somewhere accessible by all web servers?  I'm assuming shared state is required, but if there's a way around it, would interested to learn more... (we load-balance globally, so shared state is a bit more of a challenge)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ServiceStack [Sessions](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Sessions) are essentially the User Session DTO's serialized in the registered [Caching providers](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Caching). All Caching providers except for `MemoryCacheClient` persists to a distributed data store so they're naturally load balanced by just using the same configuration.

The Auth Providers that implement `IAuthWithRequest` can authenticate on-the-fly and access protected services without prior authentication, namely:

- BasicAuthProvider
- DigestAuthProvider
- AspNetWindowsAuthProvider

But overall this would be worse performance since it has to authenticate on each request instead of a single cache hit to access the users session.

Comment: Ok, that's what I was trying to get at, if authentication can live without a session persisted.  It sounds like I should just give in and store session state in an highly available datastore, so our load balancing and failover can work without kicking users back to a login prompt. I have to say that the asp.net forms auth with the machine key trick was convenient, but being able to leverage session reliably will be as well.  Oh the world of tradeoffs...